# Build Failure when Compiling the YCSB Maven Project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, ycsb

I cloned the YCSB github project with the M2Eclipse Plugin (Import -> Maven -> Check out Maven Projects from SCM).
Now my Package Explorer shows the importet folders. But every folder, except >root has error in its pom.xml. The error says:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
>       - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
>       - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:checkstyle (execution: validate, phase: validate)
>       - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read 
>        artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 
>        from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
>        Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Now trying to compile >root folder of the project according to the Getting Started site of the YCSB Project with the command:

```
mvn clean package
```

So in Eclipse im setting clean and package as goals. It is trying to build the project end exits with the following output.

```
[INFO] YCSB Root .......................................... FAILURE [  0.686 s]
[INFO] Core YCSB .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Per Datastore Binding descriptor ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] YCSB Datastore Binding Parent ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Accumulo DB Binding ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Aerospike DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cassandra DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Couchbase Binding .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] DynamoDB DB Binding ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ElasticSearch Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Gemfire DB Binding ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] HBase DB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hypertable DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Infinispan DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JDBC DB Binding .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] MongoDB Binding .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Redis DB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Tarantool DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] YCSB Release Distribution Builder .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.040 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-09T09:27:59+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have either a proxy or firewall problem `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org`....

Comment: Check if you build works on command line first.

Comment: Thanks it works now!

Comment: How did you fix it? @ma

Comment: How did you fix it @maxkra?

Comment: @user3339691 see the first comment. That command worked for me.